# Moodle Database API error : Get quiz marks for all sections of one course for one user

Tags: moodle

I am trying to get total marks obtained by a particular user, for a particular course for all the sections of that course.

The following query works and gives correct results with mysql, but not with Databse API calls

$sql = "SELECT d.section as section_id,d.name as section_name, sum(a.sumgrades) AS marks FROM mdl_quiz_attempts a, mdl_quiz b, mdl_course_modules c, mdl_course_sections d WHERE a.userid=6 AND b.course=4 AND a.quiz=b.id AND c.instance=a.quiz AND c.module=14 AND a.sumgrades>0 AND d.id=c.section GROUP BY d.section"

I tried different API calls, mainly I would want

$DB->get_records_sql($sql);

The results from API calls are meaningless. Any suggestion?

PS : This is moodle 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to do something similar, only without getting the sections. You only need the course and user id. I hope this helps you.

```
global $DB;

// get all attempts & grades from a user from every quiz of one course 
$sql = "SELECT qa.id, qa.attempt, qa.quiz, qa.sumgrades AS grade, qa.timefinish, qa.timemodified, q.sumgrades, q.grade AS maxgrade
        FROM {quiz} q, {quiz_attempts} qa
        WHERE q.course=".$courseid."
        AND qa.quiz = q.id
        AND qa.userid = ".$userid."
        AND state = 'finished'
        ORDER BY qa.timefinish ASC"; 
$exams = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);

// calculate final grades from sum grades
$grades = array();
foreach($exams as $exam) {
    $grade = new stdClass;
    $grade->quiz = $exam->quiz;
    $grade->attempt = $exam->attempt;
    // sum to final
    $grade->finalgrade = $exam->grade * ($exam->maxgrade / $exam->sumgrades);
    $grade->grademax = $exam->maxgrade;
    $grade->timemodified = $exam->timemodified;
    array_push($grades, $grade);
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly same as getting sum of grades for all sections of a particular course. I wanted for every section.

Answer (score 0):

This works in latest moodle version. Moodle 2.9. Although I am still open for better solution as this is really hacky way of getting deeper analytics about user's performance.